# Creating a function that loops through page numbers

Tags: r, web-scraping, dplyr, tidyverse, rvest

I have a script that it importing data, which looks like this:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)
library(magrittr)

page_number <- 1:20

base_url <- read_html("https://247sports.com/Season/2021-Football/CompositeRecruitRankings/?ViewPath=~%2FViews%2FSkyNet%2FPlayerSportRanking%2F_SimpleSetForSeason.ascx&Page=1")

rankings <- base_url %>% html_nodes(".meta , .score , .position , .rankings-page__name-link") %>%
  html_text() %>% 
  str_trim %>% 
  str_split("   ") %>% 
  unlist %>%
  matrix(ncol = 4, byrow = T) %>% 
  as.data.frame
```

You will notice in the `base_url`, at the very end, it includes `&Page=1`. Well, I'm trying to do that for 20 pages, hence the:

`page_number <- 1:20`

What would be the most efficient way to loop those numbers into the URL without having to write 20 different sets of code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `paste0` or `sprintf` to construct all the URL's

```
all_urls <- paste0("https://247sports.com/Season/2021-Football/CompositeRecruitRankings/?ViewPath=~%2FViews%2FSkyNet%2FPlayerSportRanking%2F_SimpleSetForSeason.ascx&Page=", 1:20)
```

You can then iterate over each URL and extract the data needed.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

rankings <- map(all_urls, ~.x %>% read_html %>%
            html_nodes(".meta , .score , .position , .rankings-page__name-link") %>%
            html_text() %>% 
            str_trim %>% 
            str_split("   ") %>% 
            unlist %>%
            matrix(ncol = 4, byrow = T) %>% 
            as.data.frame)
```

Comment: Thank you, but any idea why I keep getting this error?


`Error in UseMethod("xml_find_all") : 
  no applicable method for 'xml_find_all' applied to an object of class "character"`

Comment: sorry, I forgot to include `read_html`. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Proper legend. Thank you. One more question, if you don't mind: What would be the most effiicient way to turn this into a dataframe at the end? When I run `rankings[1:20] %>% as.data.frame()` It does not do what I need.

Comment: If you want it into one dataframe use `map_df` in place of `map` and it will bind all the rows.